# Unable to add new entry in datatable c#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

i'm trying to add a new row to my datatable.

I've no error while running this code but nothing happened in my table.

Here's my code :

```
        string table = "`DONNEE ENTRANT`";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From " + table, _conn);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);


        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(table);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

        row["CODE LIAISON"] = "TEST";

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();

        adapter.Update(dataTable);
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong (in this way, I know that we can run command with oleDb but really don't like this way ...).

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting that new row to end up in the database?

Comment: Check the query of the updateCommand of the adapter

Comment: AS  Michael Perrenoud said, this code does not insert new row in your db. Just your datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're doing it appears you want that new row to end up in the database. So remove this line:

```
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

because that's changing the `RowState` to `Unchanged` and you need it left at `Added`. Further, you need to make sure that your `adapter` has an `InsertStatement` defined so it can use it.

Comment: ok looks better now, got a exception raised now I'm gonna check by myself how to fix this but thanks for the tips about this line, helps a lot ! :)

Comment: @3wic, fantastic! I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [] instead of `` but I believe the answer to correct your problem was already given by @Michael Perrenoud